# Vim - Why is 'filetype' sometimes empty even though I open an existing file

Tags: vim, macvim

Sometimes, apparently at random, Vim decides not to figure out what filetype we've opened. I'm not sure why, so please excuse my vague question.

Any idea why it happens and how to mitigate it? I'm opening a .php file.

I've set `filetype` to `on` in my vimrc.

Comment: if the opened file type is not recognized by vim, the filetype would be empty. Or, if you open vim without any file, filetype is empty too. what file did you open?

Comment: @Kent Filetype wasn't empty. It was php

Comment: you better change the title of your question.

Comment: @Kent yep you're correct!

Comment: When this happens, could you do `:filetype<CR>` to check if it is active?

Comment: We'll need more on the context: plugins and ftplugins activated, ...
For instance, lately I've discovered that executing `:bufdo` just after vim has been launched with several files (i.e. `gvim *.cpp`) will prevent any syntax detection, or ftplugin execution (however `&ft` is still set). Which is because `&eventignore` is set by `:bufdo`.
So, it's likely that at some point a script/command opens your file with `eventignore` preventing ft detection. And then it's too late, the file has already been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim doesn't itself recognize filetypes, plugins for various languages do that for you, specifically ftplugins. Generally they will have an autocommand defined within them, eg.)

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead todo.txt,*.task,*.tasks  setfiletype task
```

Such a file is placed under ftplugin directory and generally named .vim. Although it can vary and can be complicated in certain circumstances, but you should get the general idea from the simple example.

So for files VIM doesn't recognize or there isn't a ftplugin for that type, it will be empty.

Comment: `ftplugin`s do not affect filetypes; Vim only refers to them once a filetype has been established. Filetypes are detected by `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` and `$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim` by default, and by `~/.vim/ftdetect/*`, `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, and `~/.vim/scripts.vim` if they exist.

Comment: That's right, but for new or unknown filtypes, like in the case for 'task' in the example I gave above, an ftplugin simply tells VIM which filetype it is.

Comment: `ftplugin` has nothing to do with detection. `~/.vim/ftplugin/example.vim` will not be read unless the filetype has been established as `example`. Please refer to [`:help filetype.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html).

Comment: That's right, but in case of example, it would establish the filetype to be 'example' based purely on the extension on the file, but not automatically set the filetype for the buffer. Please refer to [:help new-filetype](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype)

Comment: No, it would not; please try it before arguing it. That `:help` refers to `ftdetect`, not `ftplugin`, as I initially said. Filetypes are not established based on extension unless there's an `au` for that extension in `.vim/ftdetect/*` or in any of the `.vimrc`, `filetype.vim`, or `scripts.vim` files. As I said, `.vim/ftplugin/example.vim` will not be sourced unless `filetype=example` already. You can execute `:scriptnames` after loading a `*.example` file to verify this.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I guess I got confused between ftdetect & ftplugin, thanks for the clarification.